# Based on number of clicks display form in different component in angular

Tags: angular

I have button in a component which works as a incrementer and another button which is submit button which will redirect me to the form page so based on the number of times I clicked the increment button I want to display those many number of forms in another component

really appreciate if anyone could help me out with this...thanks in advance

Comment: Use BehaviorSubject to keep the value of formNumbers, then update it with submit method and in other component get the formNumbers from BehaviorSubject and display desired number of forms.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   // Create a Service like this in the project.



export class MessageService {

  public message = new Subject<string>();

  setMessage(value: string) {
    this.message.next(value);
  }
}

 //   and then use this service in component like this.


  export class FirstComponent {

  constructor(public messageService:MessageService) { }

  setMessage(event) {
    this.messageService.setMessage(event.value);
  }
}


   //  and use this in another Component where you want to show value like this.


  export class SecondComponent {

  message: string;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.messageService.message.subscribe(
      (message) => {
        this.message = message;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```